# Congruence $16^{(x^ 2+x+1)} \equiv 4 \mod 11$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, congruences, totient-function, primitive-roots

Given the congruence $16^{x^2+x+1}≡ 4 \mod 11$

I'm not necessarily sure how to approach this problem if someone can help me head in the right direction since 16 is not a primitive root of mod 11 I can't reduce the equation $x^2+x+1≡ 0 \mod 10$

since using taking the euler quotient of 11 gives 10.

I would guess to divide by 4 but I know that 4 is not a primitive root of mod 11 either.

Answer (score 2):

Note that since $16 \equiv 5 \text{ mod } 11$, we have $5^{x^2+x+1} \equiv 4 \text{ mod } 11$. Now we know $5^3 \equiv 4 \text{ mod } 11$, so $x^2+x+1 \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 5$ (because the order of 5 is 5 in $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$). A quick calculation shows  $x \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 5$ or $x \equiv 3 \text{ mod } 5$. You only have to check for 1, 2 and 3 in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, because a polynomial of degree 2 over a field has at most 2 roots.

Comment: Bzzzt. $5^5=3125=11*284+1$. And thanks for the downvote, I need those so badly. Can you make up some more aliases and downvote me some more, please?

Comment: @user5713492 Your attitude is out of line. If someone else has an incorrect answer, you can say so without being churlish.

Comment: @Théophile: I wasn't being churlish about his incorrect answer, but about his downvote of my correct answer. What am I supposed to do in such a situation? I could downvote him right back, but it would be my first ever downvote, and I am not fond of engaging in tit-for-tat like that in any context.

Comment: It is edited. I am new to this, and did not know downvotes are not taken so mildly.

Comment: @user5713492 "What am I supposed to do in such a situation?" Well, you could civilly point out his or her mistake. Perhaps the downvote was a misunderstanding and will get removed after you do so. Regardless, losing a couple of imaginary points on an internet site isn't really a good justification for petulant remarks.

Comment: The effect of the downvote is that his plagiarized answer sits above mine and so gets read more than my original answer, even though we both got the same number of upvotes. I suppose that's the way we like it on this web site. Plagiarism always trumps creativity in academia however, so I wish the downvoter a long and happy career in that endeavor.

Comment: @M.Van Welcome to the site! Don't worry, not everyone takes voting so personally... :)

Answer (score 1):

Using Property $\#12$ of [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Congruence.html), we have $2x^2+2x\equiv-1\pmod5$

$$\iff-2\equiv2(2x^2+2x)=(2x+1)^2-1\iff(2x+1)^2\equiv-1\equiv4$$

$$\iff2x+1\equiv\pm2$$

If $2x+1\equiv2\iff2x\equiv1\equiv6\iff x\equiv3$

If $2x+1\equiv-2\iff2x\equiv-3\equiv2\iff x\equiv1$

Answer (score 0):

But $2$ is a primitive root $\pmod{11}$, so you can consider $2^{4(x^2+x+1)}\equiv2^2\pmod{11}$ same as $4(x^2+x+1)\equiv2\pmod{10}$. Dividing both sides and the modulus by $2$, we get $2(x^2+x+1)\equiv1\pmod{5}$. Then we can multiply by $3$, being the reciprocal of $2$, to get $x^2+x+1\equiv x^2+6x+1\equiv3\pmod{5}$, where we have taken the liberty of adding $5x\equiv0\pmod{5}$. Then we can complete the square to get $(x+3)^2-9+1\equiv3\pmod{5}$, or $(x+3)^2\equiv11\equiv1\pmod{5}$. Thus $x+3\equiv\pm1\pmod{5}$, so the solutions are $x\equiv-2\equiv3\pmod{5}$ or $x\equiv-4\equiv1\pmod{5}$.